# SSL on both CNAME URL and destination

Tags: ssl, cname-record

We host several secure web applications for customers.

The customer would set up a CNAME alias to map their subdomain to our subdomain

eg. customer HTTPS URL `app.customersite.com/App` maps to our HTTPS URL `customer.hostingserver.com/App`

The customer allows us to host their SSL key & certificate which has a common name of  `app.customersite.com`.

However, historically, the customer also has access to the `customer.hostingserver.com` URL. But if they access this URL, the SSL certificate is not trusted as the domain name does not match.

They have asked us to redirect `customer.hostingvendor.com` back to `app.customersite.com` somehow so both URLs would accept the SSL certificate - but surely this would set up a circular link?

Is there any way of having both these URLs working - or do we just need to convince the customer not to try and access our URL directly?

Many Thanks

Comment: A redirect wouldn't help; the SSL negotiation happens before the redirect happens. You need to have SSL certificates matching the hostname the client is using.

Comment: OK - thank you - I thought that would be the case. We need to convince our customers to stop using the link to our domain and use their own one. Perhaps a solution is to delete our sub domain, and generate a new one that that their end users don't know about. Then they'll need to go through the CNAME alias.

Comment: Or you make SSL certificates that include your domain as a Subject Alternate Name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: each URL will need to be served using a certificate appropriate for the name in use.

This could either be a multi-domain SAN cert used for both, or two separate certificates.

Comment: OK - thanks for confirming this. We don't really want to present a certificate with our domain in - they should be using the customer's certificate with just their domain in. I think a bit of re-education is needed - or as I commented above, we'll change our sub-domain and get them to change the alias so that end users won't be able to connect on the old URL they have. Thank you for your time.